# Differ between ValueChanged by user or automatically on Slider

Tags: c#, wpf, events, slider

I have a WPF application that includes a `Slider sli`, which in general fires a method on the `ValueChanged`-event. In addition, in certain cases the maximal and minimal values of `sli` are changed. Now I have realized that in those cases the `Value` of `sli` might change in the case that it was out of range of the new max/min values. This will also fire `ValueChanged`. In addition I sometimes have to adjust `Value` programmatically, which will of course also fire `ValueChanged.

Now, I only wish to execute the method if the user changed `Value`, but not if it was forcefully changed, because it went out of range or when I change it in code.

My attempt was using the `DragCompleted`-event, but I do wish to fire the event continuously while the user drags the slider head. Another attempt was to simply remove the method from the event handler for `ValueChanged` before a max/min-change or in-code-update and add the method afterwards. Here, I am not sure if that is really the cleanest and especially the fastest solution performance-wise.

Thus, I wanted to ask if someone might have a nicer solution, maybe something that is actually commenly known, however, I couldn't find anything on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be for you to set a bit flag somewhere and only handle the event if the flag has the appropriate value:

```
bool isSystemFired = false;
```

And then in your event handler:

```
if(isSystemFired)
{
    isSystemFired = false;
    return;
}
```

And, obviously, before your automated code does anything to trigger the event handler you can set the flat to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here I might see a small (I don't know how small or big) issue in terms of performance. Whenever a user is dragging the slider, in code I would have to check multiple times a second if that was a user or system-event. But yes you are right, this is quite obviously a very simple and quick solution!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the ValueChanged event you can use the `Binding.SourceUpdated` event to detect dedicated user input. The SourceUpdated event is only triggered by explicit user input.

On the slider set the `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` property to true.

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" Value="{Binding SliderValue, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></Slider>
```

The parent container of the slider can handle the SourceUpdate event

```
<Grid Binding.SourceUpdated="Slider_TargetUpdated">

private void Slider_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Postlagerkarte. This does look like an interesting and good approach, but would that event Trigger continuously when I drag the slider? If you only get a trigger on `SourceUpdated`, it seems to me you would only get a single event on this, or do I understand this wrong?

Comment: If you set the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged the event is raised for every tick on the slider.

Comment: I have just tried your solution and the event is never triggered. Not when I change the slider value, nor when it's changed in code. Is there something missing?

Comment: You have to put the Binding.SourceUpdated on the parent control of the slider, not on the slider itself. On the slider you have to set the NotifyOnSourceUpdated. Can you post the your code?

Comment: I have done that, just as you have said: `<Grid Binding.SourceUpdated="Slider_TargetUpdated" Background="White"><Slider x:Name="Slider1" Value="{Binding SliderValue, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/></Grid>`

And in my `MainWindow`-code I have the handler `private void Slider_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{ isTriggered = true; }`

Comment: Does your viewmodel has the SliderValue property?

Comment: No, it doesnt seem to have the property. Sorry, I am still quite new to bindings in WPF and I might need a more direct information.