# WPF Slider event which occurs only when the value is changed by the user

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, media-player, seekbar

I am making a music player in which I need to create a seek. Now I have done it in WinForms with a TrackBar in this way:

- Use a Timer to keep the position of the media and the value of the TrackBar synced.
- Use the `Scroll` event to change the media position when the user drags the TrackBar's thumb.

But in WPF, there is no `Scroll` event and the `ValueChanged` event fires even when the value is changed in code. So, when I use a `DispatcherTimer` to update the slider position, even then the `ValueChanged` event is fired which in turn changes the media position. As a result, the media doesn't play properly.

So I need an Event which fires only when the value of a `Slider` is changed by the user.

I have already come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593774/differ-between-valuechanged-by-user-or-automatically-on-slider) but it doesn't have a proper answer.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ValueChanged` event-handler, check for some properties to see for user interaction.

```
IsFocused, IsMouseDirectlyOver, IsMouseOver, IsKeyboardFocused, IsKeyboardFocusWithin
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I solved it by using the DragStarted and DragCompleted events. Your answer helped me to get to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this: first, define a class variable:

```
private double newValue = 0;
```

Then, whenever you want to change the slider's value in your code, first store the new value:

```
newValue = <<whatever you need>>;
slider1.Value = newValue;
```

And then include the following check in your event handler:

```
private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (e.NewValue != newValue)
    {
       newValue = e.NewValue;
       // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```